# How to import data from Magento 1.9 into Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, magento-1.9

Having Laravel Framework 5.5.40
I need to import data from Magento 1.9
I found this
https://github.com/michaelkmartin/laravel-magento-integration
plugin

Bit it is Compatible with Laravel 4 only.

I tried to install it and got errors:

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package tinyrocket/magento 1.0.* is satisfiable by tinyrocket/magento[1.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

Can you advice some Compatible with Laravel 5.5 tool ?

Thanks!